# what is advantage of using MPI_Send_init instead of MPI_Send

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

I can't understand what is difference between using `MPI_Send_init` with `MPI_Start` and `MPI_Send`. It seems like I should be able to use request that was created using `MPI_Send_init` multiple times to avoid extra copying of arguments like in `MPI_Send` but using same request multiple times leads to error. I have following example:

```cpp
MPI_Request req[1];
MPI_Send_init(matrix, MATRIX_SIZE, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req);

if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Start(req);
    MPI_Start(req);
} else {
    MPI_Recv(matrix, MATRIX_SIZE, MPI_INT, 
             MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Recv(matrix, MATRIX_SIZE, MPI_INT, 
             MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

It's generating such error:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Start
*** reported by process [1722744833,0]
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
*** MPI_ERR_REQUEST: invalid request
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Am I doing it wrong? If so, where's an error? And is it possible to save much time using `MPI_Send_init`?

Comment: you need to `MPI_Wait(req, ...)` before `MPI_Start(req)` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MPI_Start` is non-blocking, you are trying to have two simultaneous sends with the same buffer. That doesn't make sense. Secondly, it would mean the request is re-activated before it completes. Your implementation tells you so.

In other words: do a `wait` on the request before you `start` again.

Comment: Is there a way to get a perfomance boost by using ``MPI_Send_init`` with ``MPI_Start`` instead of ``MPI_Send_init``?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. The alternatives are: multiple `Send` or `Isend` calls, vs one `Send_init` and then multiple `Start` calls. The persistent calls have a possibility for higher performance because internal bookkeeping for routing & buffer management need be done only once.

Answer (score 0):

TTBOMK, there is usually (almost) no performance gain to be expected when using `MPI_Send_init` over `MPI_Send`.
But timing your application will give you the best answer as it's implementation dependent.